Get-MgUserCalendarView : Access is denied -
Im trying to create a Daily update for all staff on their calendar entries which then will get sent to all management members.
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Calendars.Read", "Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared"

$timeZone = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::FindSystemTimeZoneById("New Zealand Standard Time")

$startDate = [System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId((Get-Date), $timeZone.Id).Date
$endDate = $startDate.AddDays(1)

$users = Get-MgUser -Filter "accountEnabled eq true" -All

$emailBody = ""

foreach ($user in $users) {
    $userId = $user.Id
    $calendarEntries = Get-MgUserCalendarView -UserId $userId -StartDateTime $startDate -EndDateTime $endDate

    if ($calendarEntries) {
        $emailBody += "Calendar Entries for $($user.UserPrincipalName):`n"

        foreach ($entry in $calendarEntries) {
            $emailBody += "`t- Subject: $($entry.Subject)`n"
        }

        $emailBody += "`n"
    }
}

if ($emailBody) {
    Write-Output "Email body constructed successfully" 
    Write-Output $emailBody

    $Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
    $Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
    $Mail.Subject = "Today's Calendar Entries"
    $Mail.Body = $emailBody
    $Mail.Display()
} else {
    Write-Output "No calendar entries found for any user"
}

Disconnect-MgGraph

In theory the script should loop through each user, view their daily entries and then open outlook and send me the updates.
But I keep getting these errors..
Get-MgUserCalendarView : Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.

Can you pick a random user and try Invoke-MgGraphRequest GET 'v1.0/users/{userId}/calendar/calendarView?startDateTime=2024-08-14T22:21:07&endDateTime=2024-08-15T22:21:07', replace {userId} with an actual user's Id (GUID)

Connected - can see @odata.context info and Value

What's the security context you connected under with connect-mggraph  eg are you using a Delegate user or a service principal and app permissions. Also $users = Get-MgUser -Filter "accountEnabled eq true" -All would also return all enabled Entra users whether they had a Exchange Mailbox or not.

So the API works fine, does this issue happen for all users or just some users? The issue I see in your code is that you're not passing the dates in the expected format. The expected format is the s DateTime format (i.e.: $startDate.ToString('s'))

Just because you can, does not mean you should... I don't know where you are from, but in EU there are some strict privacy laws. Sharing these details with management may only be allowed IF stated in an employee privacy notice.
I have seen requests by managers which I have denied since they did not abide to laws and regulations. They may not even be aware this might be an issue. So my advice would be to check with a privacy specialist before actually activating this script once it works.

So no law related issues for us as everyone shares their calendars with the management team, this is for daily planning.
I managed to get it working though, by not using mg-graph, which made things heaps easier.
